# phpMyAdmin apparently ignoring POST data, no error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am running MAMP on my OSX dev environment, and it recently notified me that it could auto-update phpMyAdmin to version 4.6.5.2. I did so, and all seemed to be well, I was able to browse my databases as before.

Soon I learned that some things weren't working. When I take actions that use a GET request, such as clicking the Browse tab on a database, it works. When I do anything requiring POST, such as a Search, or an SQL query, it ignores the request and reloads the page, no error message appears on-screen.

No errors or warnings appear in my MySQL, Apache, or PHP  log files. The problem occurs on all databases, and it's only affecting phpMyAdmin--other locally hosted sites accept POST requests as normal. I am able to read and write to the databases though other channels (e.g., command line, PHP scripts, etc).

Has anyone else encountered this?

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing it?

I'm currently trying to roll back the version, but I need to figure out how.

Comment: Additional info: No errors in the browser console, this is what's returned by phpMyAdmin: `{"reload_flag":"1","success":false,"error":"<a class=\"hide\" id=\"update_recent_tables\" href=\"index.php?ajax_request=1&amp;recent_table=1&amp;token=ea3ea6a0a6ffc113f7abd971b1651c6f\"><\/a>"}`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same. It looks like I have resolved the problem by clearing cookies. Also switching between different auth_type(http, cookie, config) modes in config.inc.php could help.